Null value when running a Identity Server method
I'm trying to setup a very simple OpenIddict project, but I'm having a lot of problems and questions to make it run.
My project have included just OpenIddict.AspNetCore library and is using Net6.
The code is just:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using OpenIddict.Abstractions;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddServer(options =>
    {
        options
            .AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
            .RequireProofKeyForCodeExchange();

        options
            .SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/authorize")
            .SetTokenEndpointUris("/token");

        options
            .UseAspNetCore()
            .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
            .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough();

        options.EnableDegradedMode(); //To suppress calls to the DB
    });

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.MapGet("/authorize", async (HttpContext context) =>
{
    var request = context.GetOpenIddictServerRequest();
    if (request != null && request.IsAuthorizationCodeFlow())
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Call to /authorize received");
    }
    throw new Exception("Invalid request");
});

app.UseRouting();

app.Run();

When I run this, the request variable in my /authorize delegate is always null.
Also, I expect to have the endpoint .well-known/openid-configuration, but it returns 404.
I don't want to include EF yet, because I prefer to see the working flow first (And could be another Db implementation than EF). And, this is a recurrent problem in the basic examples: they have too much implementation details that make very hard to find the bare flows for a IdentityServer.
My objective is just to have the Auth Code flow.

To fix the null request variable and the 404 error for the OpenID configuration endpoint:

Ensure OpenIddict middleware is invoked correctly by adding app.UseAuthentication() and app.UseAuthorization() before app.UseRouting().
Configure the OpenID configuration endpoint using SetIssuer() method in OpenIddict server options.


That was fast! UseAuthentication() and UseAuthorization() was intentionally omitted on my side, because the call to /authorize, /exchange and /token will be anonymous and I will have no more endpoints (for now). But effectivelly, it worked after I added it.
